Grub dual boot Windows11 not detected anymore
I installed a new partition of Ubuntu 24 on the disk, but I accidentally deleted the Windows Boot Manager, as I wasn't planning to use it after installing the GRUB bootloader. Now, when I boot, I only see the Ubuntu option, but the Windows partition and other partitions are still visible on the disk.
I ran os-prober and update-grub, and I disabled Secure Boot. I also run boot-repair, but it didn’t solve the issue. Here's the report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/b5T8PvzVxw/.
Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Good chance that it is because a Microsoft patch : https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2024/08/windows-update-breaking-linux-dualboot-fix

Grub chainloads the windows boot loader to boot windows, so if you deleted the windows bootloader, you have nothing to boot windows. Grub setup, seeing no windows bootloader, so not include it in the boot menu. Restore the deleted Windows bootloader, but that's not an Ubuntu issue.
